# Fetching plist at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app where I would like to run/test on 2 different servers, and currently what I do is compile a pair of different executables. Each has a different plist containing the server information but are otherwise the same. Then I just read them in like this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

However, this is becoming a hassle as we are building more frequently and planning on adding more servers. Is there a way to have to program fetch the plist from a folder at runtime, so I won't have to compile multiple times for each build? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I guess a way to rephrase this question is:
How can I read from a plist that is not pre-compiled into the application bundle?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined a value in the info.plist which could store the type or name of the server, you could potentially randomly assign a server on a per-app basis (`arc4rand()`), and retrieve the value at runtime with the right address.